# Put a for loop iteration in a boostrap group list at button click

Tags: javascript, html

Put a for loop iteration in a Bootstrap group list button click
I have a lab about addEventListener, where in a click of a button shows your for loop with office locations.

```js
const grupList = document.querySelector("ul");
console.log(grupList);

const listItems = document.querySelector("li");
console.log(listItems);

const offices = document.getElementById("ofLocations");
let officeLocations = ["New York", "London", "Paris", "Tokyo", "Sydney"];


function getOfficeLocations (arr){
      for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
    offices.addEventListener("click",  getOfficeLocation {});
}

getOfficeLocation(officeLocations);
```

This is what I have done so far.

Comment: Do you have any question about this code?

Comment: Can you edit this so it's more like a question?